# How can we call 2 models in one controller in Node Express JS...?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new in Nodejs and I am using express JS framework with MVC pattern
I want to get data from two different tables (with use of two different functions in model) in single
controller function, Can I do this ?

1. How can I pass parameters to two different model
2. How can we manage result/response from two different model ?

-- Here is my Model

```
sensorModel.getAllSensorSite=function(result){
    sql.query("SELECT * FROM site",function(err,res){
        if(err) {
            return result(err,null);
        }
        else{
         return result(null,res);
        }
    });
}

sensorModel.getAllSensorRowss=function(result){
    sql.query("SELECT * FROM rowss",function(err,res){
        if(err) {
            return result(err,null);
        }
        else{
         return result(null,res);
        }
    });
}
```

-- Here is my Controller

```
sensorController.index=function(req,res,next){
    sensorModel.getAllSensorSite(function(err,site){
        if(err){
                throw err;
        }else{
            res.json({ site });
        }       
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this method, you're sending queries to database but you can't wait for their reply. I would recommend to use [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) to be able to wait for database responses or to use an ORM (like [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize)) along with `await/async`

Comment: thanks @AlexandruDuDu but I did it by myself yesterday :)

Comment: Maybe you can post the solution and mark it as the correct one so other people can have it when they reach this question